# Timeout error when trying to use npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I try to run this, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser (over 30000ms)
```

This is what happens in the log:

```
205 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
206 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
206 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
206 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
206 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
207 verbose type body-timeout
208 verbose stack FetchError: Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser (over 30000ms)
208 verbose stack     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:189:16)
208 verbose stack     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
208 verbose stack     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
209 verbose cwd C:\Users\Acc\mern-todo-app
210 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
211 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
212 verbose node v12.16.2
213 verbose npm  v6.14.4
214 error Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2fparser (over 30000ms)
215 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm pretty new to this so I have no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 13):

I also faced this issue, I tried with this code by adding timeout into it and it worked like a charm.

```
npx create-react-app my-app -timeout=60000
```

Here 60000 is 60 seconds. You can increase the time as per your choice.

Comment: This worked flawlessly !

Comment: For me the timeout needed to be `60000000`. haha

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing cache and rerun the command. `$ npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Internet's working fine, there's nothing wrong with my connection from what I can tell.

Comment: Tried it a few more times, both before and after clearing the cache, and I get the same error. Though the thing it's trying to fetch in the error message changes each time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, someone has my case. In my case the error was reporting a line like this: `npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.`
I just installed those packages one-by-one, by typing:

```
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react-dom
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react-scripts
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error cra-template
```

After that, I just run `npx create-react-app appname` and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I also faced similar issue and was able to fix the issue with following commands:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar error while creating react app for the first time after installing NodeJS. It was resolved by running below commands in sequence:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -timeout flag `npm create react app -timeout=1000`. Note => timeout flag take tge value in mili second

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve it using clear cache, delete proxy etc. So, I tried yarn and it worked like a charm!

`yarn create react-app project-name`

Answer (score 0):

If you run it on Windows, try to open shell windiw as an admin, had the same error and it helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar error while creating react app for the first time after installing NodeJS. It was not solved by running below commands in sequence:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

I also faced this issue again again, I tried with this code by adding timeout into 12000000  and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the timeout problem while trying to install react app by using

`npx create-react-app app-name`

The solution is to uninstall node, then go to [node js official site](https://nodejs.org/en/)
to download a new one, then install and try

`npx create-react-app my-app`

It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of my antivirus(node32) and after I paused **RealTime Protection** the problem went away.

Answer (score -3):

I'm getting this issue after giving lots of command its and working and while creating app after few seconds lots of errors found
If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
this are errors
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AZTECH\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-31T02_54_23_036Z-debug-0.log

Comment: More of a statement/comment rather then an answer